# XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject object is always nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmppframework

I am using the code below to get unread messages count. However, `XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *user` is always `nil`. The chat function works fine but i can't get the unread messages count.

```
XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *user = [self.xmppRosterStorage userForJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[message fromStr] componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"]objectAtIndex:0] ]]
                                                                          xmppStream:self.xmppStream
                                                                managedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext_roster]];

NSNumber *number = user.unreadMessages;

int value = [number intValue];

number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:value + 1];

user.unreadMessages = number;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your project is not cleaned.So deep clean the project by pressing the following the keys
window+alt+shift+k.
I hope it will help for you.